# List all elements from a list created with $http.get in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new into AngularJS programming and I wrote some code, I don't get any errors, in console it gives me what I want but it dose not show on the web page. I am trying to make 2 HTTP calls, get and post, get shows me all the element I have in a list and post add an element in this list. They are working, but when I try to list all the elements it dose not show me anything :(

Here are my code:

**dataContext.js**

```
(function () {
 'use strict';
  angular.module('app').service('dataContext', ['httpService', function (httpService) {
    var service = {
        getAllUsers: getAllUsers,
        addUser: addUser,
        saveMessage: saveMessage
    };

    function getAllUsers() {
        return httpService.get("api/users");
    }

    function addUser(name) {
        return httpService.post("api/users", { name: name });
    }
```

**dashboard.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('app').controller("dashboardController", ['dataContext', function (dataContext) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getUser = function () {
        dataContext.getAllUsers().then(
            function (response) {
                alert(response.data[0].Name);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    };

    vm.postUser = function () {
        dataContext.addUser(vm.username).then(
            function (response) {
                alert("User, " + vm.username + " was added!");
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        ); 
    };
})();
```

**httpService.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app').service('httpService', ['$http', '$q', 'backendConfig', function ($http, $q, backendConfig) {
    var service = {
        get: get,
        post: post
    };

    function get(path) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(backendConfig.url + path).then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },

            function (err, status) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function post(path, data) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(backendConfig.url + path, data).then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },

            function (err, status) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return service;
}]);})();
```

and my **dashboard.html**

```
<div ng-controller="dashboardController as vm">
<button ng-click="vm.getUser()">Get</button>
<button ng-click="vm.postUser()">Post</button>
<input ng-model="vm.username" />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in vm.users">{{obj.Name}}</li>
</ul>
```

List's name is users, I have a class Users with a string Name, everything should be on point but I don't know why it dose not work. Any help will be awesome

Thank you

Comment: To begin with replace `alert(response.data[0].Name);` with `vm.users = response.data;`. What further errors you get?

Comment: @jaboja it worked, haha.. it make sense, when I ask for data I had to save them into this.users. Thank you so muuuuuuuuuch <3

Comment: @jaboja your comment should be the answer then, and it should be upvoted and selected as correct.

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
alert(response.data[0].Name);
```

with

```
vm.users = response.data;
```